# Landscaped Longtables

Tags: longtable, rotating, landscape

I am currently using the `longtable` environment, but I would like to change the orientation of the table and make it landscape. Using the `lscape` environment I am only able to modify the orientation of the page, rather than that of the table itself. Could you help me please?

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lscape}
```

Then the syntax to insert a longtable:

```
 \begin{document}
 \begin{landscape}
 \begin{center}
 \scriptsize
 \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{8cm}|}\hline\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\textbf{Text1}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{\textbf{Text2}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{p{8cm}|}{\textbf{Text3}}\\ \hline 
 \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{p{3cm}}
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\ 
 \hline\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\textbf{Text1}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{\textbf{Text2}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{p{8cm}|}{\textbf{Text3}}\\\hline 
 \endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\caption[Caption]{Caption}\label{label-caption} 
\endfoot
\caption[Caption]{Caption}\label{label-caption} 
\endlastfoot

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code runs fine with me and I get a table in the landscape. Can you give more details on your problem?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want to achieve. If you provided to images, one showing what you get and another one showing what you want, it would be easier to understand your desires. You can draw the images as sketches, they needn't come from LaTeX.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your replies, apparently it now works fine.